Job 25: 6 and the son of man
In Job 25:6 there are two Hebrew words translated worm. The second one states, the son of man which is a worm. That same Hebrew word is often translated crimson as in Isaiah 1:18. Therefore, is that word and passage referring to Jesus?

Job 25:6 - how much less man, who is but a maggot, and the son of man,
who is but a worm!”
Isa 1:18 - “Come now, let us reason together,” says the LORD. “Though
your sins are like scarlet, they will be as white as snow; though they
are as red as crimson, they will become like wool.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you may be up fore something here.

The life cycle of the crimson worm is a wonderful thing, isn't it. It is amazing how that little insect points to the work of Jesus on the cross. And God not only created it that way, but deliberately told Moses to use it, so the Israelites can make the connections when the time of the Messiah arrives. You are right to pay attention to the texts, where the word tola appears. I read the whole chapter to get the context right, and somehow the content seemed familiar. Especially the last two verses.

1 Then Bildad the Shuhite answered and said: 2 “Dominion and fear are
with God; he makes peace in his high heaven. 3 Is there any number to
his armies? Upon whom does his light not arise? 4 How then can man be
in the right before God? How can he who is born of woman be pure? 5
Behold, even the moon is not bright, and the stars are not pure in his
eyes; 6 how much less man, who is a maggot, and the son of man, who is
a worm!”

Moon and stars, plus two Hebrew words for human (enosh & adam), in the same text. Where else can we find them? Psalm 8. Bongo!

1 O Lord, our Lord, how majestic is your name in all the earth! You
have set your glory above the heavens. 2 Out of the mouth of babies
and infants, you have established strength because of your foes, to
still the enemy and the avenger. 3 When I look at your heavens, the
work of your fingers, the moon and the stars, which you have set in
place, 4 what is man that you are mindful of him, and the son of man
that you care for him? 5 Yet you have made him a little lower than the
heavenly beings and crowned him with glory and honor. 6 You have given
him dominion over the works of your hands; you have put all things
under his feet, 7 all sheep and oxen, and also the beasts of the
field, 8 the birds of the heavens, and the fish of the sea, whatever
passes along the paths of the seas. 9 O Lord, our Lord, how majestic
is your name in all the earth!

It is hard to say whether the author/authors of Job paraphrases Psalm 8 or vice versa. What we know, though, is that Psalm 8 is definitely messianic. It is used quite a few times in the NT, so there is no debate here:

15 But when the chief priests and the teachers of the law saw the
wonderful things he did and the children shouting in the temple
courts, “Hosanna to the Son of David,” they were indignant. 16 “Do you
hear what these children are saying?” they asked him. “Yes,” replied
Jesus, “have you never read, “ ‘From the lips of children and infants
you, Lord, have called forth your praise’?” (Matthew 21)
27 For he “has put everything under his feet.” Now when it says that
“everything” has been put under him, it is clear that this does not
include God himself, who put everything under Christ. (1 Corinthians
15)
22 And God placed all things under his feet and appointed him to be
head over everything for the church, (Ephesians 1)
5 It is not to angels that he has subjected the world to come, about
which we are speaking. 6 But there is a place where someone has
testified: “What is mankind that you are mindful of them, a son of man
that you care for him? 7 You made them a little lower than the angels;
you crowned them with glory and honor 8 and put everything under their
feet.” In putting everything under them, God left nothing that is not
subject to them. Yet at present we do not see everything subject to
them. 9 But we do see Jesus, who was made lower than the angels for a
little while, now crowned with glory and honor because he suffered
death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.
(Hebrews 2)

Job 25:5-6 doesn't seem to be the only place where we can find parallels to Psalm 8. Job 7:17 also uses the same phrase as the verse 4 of the psalm:

17 What is man that You should exalt him, that You should set Your
heart upon him, 18 that You attend to him every morning, and test him
every moment?

So it seems, more than likely, that the book of Job repurposes the psalm and expands on its content. I would not be surprised if we could find more verses from other psalms there too. As a matter of fact, I am 100% convinced it is the case:

16 For dogs surround me; a band of evil men encircles me; they have
pierced my hands and feet. (Psalm 22)
13 His archers surround me. He pierces my kidneys without mercy and
spills my gall on the ground. (Job 16)

It is not intuitive and sometimes even messy, but those messianic verses from the Psalms must be deliberately woven into the book of Job.
We should not forget that Job, the righteous one that suffered unjustifiably, is a great OT picture of the Messiah. The last chapter has Job repeatedly called a servant of God and hints at the resurrection of his children
All in all, I think you may be up fore something here.

Please clarify "without no reason". Do you intend a double negative which would equal "for a reason"?

@C. Stroud There. I have fixed it for you. I made a mistake while editing my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Job 25:6 contains two parallel statements expressing the same truth:

how much less man, who is but a maggot,
and the son of Adam, who is but a worm!”

We should observe several things about these two statements:

Different words are used for "worm" and "maggot" but in this context, both are treated as a mechanism and sign of death and decay - that is, both are saying that humans are mortal
The word translated "worm" is תּוֹלָע (towla) and refers to a crimson-colored worm as stated in Strong's lexicon:


The Hebrew word "tola" primarily refers to a worm, specifically the
crimson or scarlet worm (Coccus ilicis), which was used in ancient
times to produce a red dye. This term is often used metaphorically in
the Bible to denote insignificance or lowliness, as well as to
describe the color scarlet or crimson, symbolizing sin or royalty.
In ancient Israel, the crimson worm was significant for its use in
producing a red dye, which was highly valued for coloring fabrics,
especially in the making of priestly garments and the tabernacle. The
process involved crushing the worm to extract the dye, symbolizing
sacrifice and transformation. The color scarlet was associated with
wealth, power, and sin, as seen in various biblical contexts.


The two words translated "man" are also distinct - אֱנוֹשׁ (enowsh) refers to any human being.  The second is אָדָם (adam) refers either to mankind generally or to Adam specifically.
In either case, both are used as collective nouns of mankind generally in this context.

CONCLUSION
This verse does not refer to messiah and is not a prophecy of Messiah.
